# Vue.js reactivity for new object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to make an object reactive for Vue.js (not present in "data", so no reactive by default).

I came across [this guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html) using Vue.set, but... How do I set an empty object reactive?

An example for explanation:

```
let app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",

  data: {
    items: [],
  },

methods: {
    setItems: function () {
        this.items[0] = {}; //how to make this reactive?
        Vue.set(this.items[0], 'name', newValue); //newValue should be updated every hour form API response
}
```

"newValue" is never updated because "{}" is not present in "data", but I don't know how to use Vue.set in this case.

Any idea on how to solve it without adding this code below?

```
data: {
    items: [{}],
  },
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: With `this.items = {}` you are replacing the initially empty array with an object. Afterwards, you're trying to access an Array `Vue.set(this.items[i], ...`. I don't see how that is supposed to work.

Comment: Can you give us data example of `items` which you expect (for example, after 3 hours) ? It helps us to understand how to use `i`, `newValue` and update `items`.

Comment: Updated the code for clearance, hope it is more clear now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the following approach?

```
setItems: function () {
    Vue.set(this.items, 0, { 'name': newValue })
}
```

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/7mejxybg/3/